# Mac OSX Monero GUI link on Getmonero seems to not work

Tags: macos

I have tried three times to download it and I only get a part file and a 'Failed' message.

Is there another (safe) place to get it, and has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download it from the official [Monero Github account](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/releases)

Comment: I am sorted now thanks, it's downloaded - can't get it to work, so I am now looking for idiot proof instructions. I see 'wrong version' bottom left - which apparently means I am running the wrong daemon. I am not running a daemon - so I have no idea what to do. I assumed once I set up wallet it would er... run like a a BTC core wallet. Seems not. Are there simple instructions for Mac users out there that do not involve CLI and terminal window stuff - which I can't do, or is this not really a version ready for people like me?

Comment: I'm pleased you've got it downloaded. Sounds like you have a new problem though so it may need a new question. Check if it has already been answered first. However, briefly, you will have to wait until the blockchain data has downloaded. This could take a few days, depending on your internet connection speed. If this has happened and you're still having problems, open a new question and give as much information as you can.

Comment: @Kuriously, have you read the FAQs here? This covers the "Wrong Version" error: https://getmonero.org/2016/12/22/monero-core-gui-beta-released.html